# source: not found in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, virtualenv

I want to activate a virtual env in shell script, so I write a simple script as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash

source ~/env/lib/bin/activate
#nohup python mock_run.py
#echo $! > save_pid.txt
```

I start the script with `sh start.sh`, but I got error as follow:

```
start.sh: 3: start.sh: source: not found
```

I run `source ~/env/lib/bin/activate` is ok, so why can not in shell script?

Comment: Make sure you're running it with bash via #!/bin/bash in the top and ``sh start.sh``. Also source has an alias ``.`` so try ``. ~/env/lib/bin/activate``

Comment: I have `#!/bin/bash` in my script, and `. ~/env/lib/bin/activate` is ok, but why `source` is not ok?

Comment: Rather, *don't* use `sh start.sh`. Run the script with `./start.sh`. Don't explicitly invoke the shell.

Answer (score 15):

Note that the [*shebang*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

is not in effect when you invoke the script with

```
sh script.sh
```

The shebang is in effect only if you call the script directly, like a binary.

---

You need to either:

```
chmod +x script.sh
./script.sh
```

to make the *shebang* line working, or call it explicitly with bash:

```
bash script.sh
```